# Core 2 MVC with JQuery Datatables

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, datatables

There is a good example on how to use JQuery Datatables with Core MVC at [Using jQuery DataTables Grid With ASP.NET CORE MVC](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-jquery-datatables-grid-with-asp-net-core-mvc/)

I download the sample project, made some modifications and it works perfectly.

However, I'm getting an error when I try to integrate this into my project.

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter 'IdStudent' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

After I click ok on the error, the table generates with the correct number of rows, but with no data:

[image]

This is my class:

```
public class GridStudent
{
    [Key]
    public int IdStudent { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

The HTML and JavaScript:

```
    <div class="container">
    <br />
    <div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;">
        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>IdStudent</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>LastName</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("#example").DataTable({
            "processing": true, // for show progress bar
            "serverSide": true, // for process server side
            "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
            "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/StudentGrid/LoadData",
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columnDefs":
            [
                {
                    "targets": [0],
                    "visible": false,
                    "searchable": false,
                }
            ],
            "columns": [
                { "data": "IdStudent", "name": "IdStudent", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Name", "name": "Name", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "LastName", "name": "LastName", "autoWidth": true },
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta)
                    { return '<a class="btn btn-info" href="/StudentGrid/Edit/' + full.IdStudent + '">Edit</a>'; }
                }
                ,
                {
                    data: null, render: function (data, type, row)
                    {
                        return "<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger' onclick=DeleteData('" + row.IdStudent + "'); >Delete</a>";
                    }
                },
            ]
        });
    });

    function DeleteData(CustomerID)
    {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ...?"))
        {
            Delete(CustomerID);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

   function Delete(CustomerID)
   {
        var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "StudentGrid/Delete";

        $.post(url, { ID: CustomerID }, function (data)
            {
                if (data)
                {
                    oTable = $('#example').DataTable();
                    oTable.draw();
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Something Went Wrong!");
                }
            });
   }
</script>
```

This is the line of code, from the controller, than returns the data:

```
return await Task.Run(() => Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = data }));
```

[image]

As you can see from the image, the controller is returning the data correctly, but for some reason DataTables can't read it.

I cross check with the sample a thousand times and I can't see a difference on the format of the data being return.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is most likely due to the casing of the serialized JSON. Your `data` properties in the column definitions within your JavaScript expect Pascal casing. At present, I expect your are serializing JSON as lower camel case rather than Pascal case (e.g. `idStudent` instead of `IdStudent`).

To serialize JSON as Pascal case, make sure you have the following in the `ConfigureServices` method in your `Startup` class:

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver
            = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver();
    });
```

Comment: nice! It worked right after i added this. Everything was showing correctly on debug though

Comment: @CalC Thanks a lot, This help me too. With my Asp.net core2.2 web app, I was able to display the list of Data with a Pagination and sorting!!! Brilliant

Comment: I loose one full day due to  this issue